# Can`t change back keyboard layout in xfce DE

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have two keyboard layouts on Xubuntu 18.04, and I have set my keyboard layout switch key to <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. The problem is that I can switch from the first layout to the second, But then I can`t switch back from the second layout to the first one.
I have found nothing on the internet and also have searched in the settings but found nothing related to this problem.

So what do you think about it?

Comment: I'm using xfce and can't reproduce this problem, when I set the keyboard layout switch to `win`+`space` it works as expected. What happens if you press `win`+`shift`+`space`, does this toggle the layout back to the first one? Another option is to add the keyboard layout plugin to your panel, so you could switch the layout with a mouse-click.

Comment: @mook765 Yes! you're right, `win`+`shift`+`space` works, But isn't there a way to use `win`+`space` for toggling back keyboard layout?

Comment: `win`+`space` and `win`+`shift`+`space` toggle the layout in different directions. This will matter when we have more than two layouts in the list. Normally it should toggle through the list and toggles to the first entry in the list if we are using the the layout which is the last in the list. I don't know why this doesn't work in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a similar issue was reported as a **bug in Xubuntu 18.04** (on Jan 2018)
and was later confirmed as such (on Jan 2019) -
see [*cannot switching keyboard layout with xfce4-keyboard-settings*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1805197).

As of now (Oct 2019), there is no indication someone is going to fix it.